# Set username/userID to boat when seat is occupied

Tags: lua, roblox

I am working on a game in which you can sail with boats. My script works but I wonder if I am doing it right?

What I'm trying to do is that as soon as you spawn a boot the name of the boot is the userID + the name of the ship.
This works fine thanks to one guy on this forum (Much Love)!
So now I wanted to write a script inside the seat as soon as another player or the player himself sits on the chair changes the name of the boat to that player name + boat name. This works, but now I have managed to get the name of the player and not his id. I prefer the ID of the player. How do you do that?

Because I get the player name instead of his id. I had to make another check to see if the boat does not already exist. Now 1 player can get 2 boats because player.Name and player.UserID do not match.

So my question is how do I get the userID instead of its name from the script below so that a player can take over the boat but not get 2 boats in the end?

I'm sorry for my bad coding i'm new to this :) Thanks for helping out!

Script inside of seat:

```
local Seat = script.Parent
local debounceCheck = false
local ChangeBoatName = script.Parent.Parent
local boatname = "ShipOnePerson"

Seat.Changed:Connect(function(player)   
    if Seat.Occupant ~= nil then
        if Seat.Occupant.Parent.Name ~= "PlayerNameHere" then
            local PlayerToNewBoat = game.Players:FindFirstChild(Seat.Occupant.Parent.Name)
            local Character = PlayerToNewBoat.Character or PlayerToNewBoat.CharacterAdded:Wait()
            if not debounceCheck then
                -- Is it Occupant?

                debounceCheck = true
                -- Mark it as Occupant, so that other handlers don't execute

                if ChangeBoatName then
    
                    local plruserid = Seat.Occupant.Parent.Name
                    local SetNameToBoat = plruserid..boatname
                    local NewBoat = ChangeBoatName
                    NewBoat.Name = SetNameToBoat
                    NewBoat.Parent = game.Workspace
            
                    print(NewBoat)
                end
                
            end
        else
            debounceCheck = false
            -- Mark it as not Occupant, so other handlers can execute again
        end
    else
            debounceCheck = false
            -- Mark it as not Occupant, so other handlers can execute again
        

end
end)
```

My second question is how can I make sure that as soon as you press the button RegenButton it first checks if there is already a boat in that place and if so how do I make sure that you cannot spawn?

Below is the code that is in the button regenbutton

```
    local cd = workspace.Regenbutton:WaitForChild('ClickDetector')
    local boat = game:GetService('ServerStorage'):WaitForChild('ShipOnePerson')
    local button = workspace:WaitForChild('Regenbutton')
    local debounce = false
    local boatname = "ShipOnePerson"
    
    cd.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(function()
    
        button.Transparency = 0.5
    end)
    
    cd.MouseHoverLeave:Connect(function()
        button.Transparency = 0
    end)
    
    cd.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
        local plruserid = player.UserId
        local SetNameToBoat = plruserid..boatname
        local plrextraboat = player.Name..boatname
        
        print(SetNameToBoat)
        local oldboat = workspace:FindFirstChild(SetNameToBoat)
        local oldboat2 = workspace:FindFirstChild(plrextraboat)
    
        if not debounce then
            if oldboat then
                oldboat:destroy()
            end
            if oldboat2 then
                oldboat2:destroy()
            end
            debounce = true
            local NewBoat = boat:Clone()
            NewBoat.Name = SetNameToBoat
            NewBoat.Parent = game.Workspace
            wait(5)
            debounce = false
        end
    
    end)
```

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how do I get the userID instead of its name

Instead of [Player.Name](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Instance/Name) use [Player.UserId](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/UserId)

My second question is how can I make sure that as soon as you press the button RegenButton it first checks if there is already a boat in that place and if so how do I make sure that you cannot spawn?

You could use [Instance.GetChildren](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetChildren) to get a list of all children, then iterate over that list in a loop. Check wether any of those children is a boat [Instance.IsA](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/IsA) and if so, check whether it is in the spawn location.

Comment: Instance.IsA() is for checking inheritance, not comparing clones.